# How can I configure a local RabbitMQ instance to be exactly like CloudAMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, cloudamqp

I am trying to use the QPID libraries to connect to CloudAMQP and am consistently getting connection refused, or connection reset errors.  If I use a locally installed RabbitMQ instance it works just fine.  I don't have any issues connecting to CloudAMQP from nodeamqplib or other solutions.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the way the CloudAMQP instance requires SSL, but I'm not sure.  I want to try and setup my local instance the exact same way CloudAMQP is configured to see if I can get more logging.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: which QPID library are you using?

Comment: Actually we figured it out.  The problem was with the specification of the virtual host.  Our code was adding a leading /, Cloud AMQP doesn't use a / in it's virtual hosts.